# Wrong Start Time displayed in Workflow email

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using a workflow email to alert the users about a new event. I am able to get the name of the event and end time of the event in email successfully using `[%Current Item:Name of Event%]` and `[%Current Item:End Time%]`.

I use `[%Current Item:Start Time%]` to get the start time but I get a date as `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 1):

1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM is usually indicative of a "zero" time, or an un-initialized time. I would log the value to the history and make sure it is not zero.

Comment: How to log the value to the history?

Comment: What tool are you using to create your workflows?

Comment: SP Designer 2010

Comment: There is an action in SP Designer called "Log to History List". Add that action and put your Start Time variable in there. It will show in your workflow history log after the workflow runs.

Comment: I added it. But it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?